# How to copy a file over SSH?

Tags: apache-2.2, ssh, putty

I need to copy a file that apparently is only accessible over SSH (http.conf). I am very ignorant in this area and have virtually no experience with using an SSH client, so my hours of trying have resulted in no progress.

I'm able to view the file using the "vi" command, but can't find a way to copy all of the lines in the file. I tried copying the file using the "scp" command, but could not get it to work.

What is the easiest way to copy a file over SSH?

Comment: What was the exact command line you used with `scp` ?

Comment: @Ladadadada - `scp ftpusername@mydomain.com:httpd.conf /pathtopublichtmlfolder/public_html`. The response was "ssh: connect to host domain.com port 22: Connection refused.

Comment: Is ssh running on port 22 on your server or is it a non-standard port?

Comment: From where to where do you want to copy `http.conf`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest way if you aren't familiar with SCP command is to download [Tunnelier](https://www.bitvise.com/ssh-client-download), when you connect with SSH to your server, you will automatically also get an file explorer window [like this](https://www.bitvise.com/files/tunnelier-sftp.png) that you can use to copy files between server and your PC with an easy drag and drop method

Comment: Wow, that was easy. After over an hour of trying with Putty, this was just drag & drop. THANK YOU!!!!!

Answer (score 2):

scp user@destinationhost:/path/to/file /path/to/file

Comment: Should "user" be "root" or any ftp username? When I remove ".com" from the website name, which is what I'm assuming you were implying by writing "destinationhost", it says "Name or service not known."

Comment: @Nate You shouldn't remove ".com" as "host.com" is your full hostname

Comment: Did you log in via SSH to invoke vi earlier?  Use the same username and same destinationhost.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like the `httpd.conf` file is already on the server you've ssh'd to, and you want to get it OFF of there to your local computer?  Since it's unlikely you're running an ssh server on your windows PC to send the file to, you'll need to use a windows SCP client, run in windows and connecting to the server, to transfer the file from the server to you.  PuTTY has a commandline [pscp.exe](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html) that you can use in a command prompt in windows, or you can use a graphical client like [WinSCP](http://winscp.net/eng/index.php).

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand transfering files over SSH has any involve in apache2 ? So I will ignore apache2
What is your Client Computer's OS ?

1. Windows :  Use WinScp , Enter Server's IP or domain , your username , your password ( or key )
2. *Unix or MacOs :  use commandline :

   - Transfer a file  `scp whatever.file yourusername@server:/path/to/somewhere/`
   - Transfer a directory `scp -r your_directory yourusername@server:/path/to/somewhere/`
   - If you have a key, use `scp -i /path/to/keyfile whatever.file yourusername@server:/path/to/somewhere/`

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

SCP local to remote copy:

scp http.conf user@remoteserver:/pathtopublichtmlfolder/public_html